# $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sup (1/n)^{1/n}=1$

Tags: real-analysis

I am quite stuck as how to how I can prove this. My attempt so far is to show that for any $x\in (0,1)$ we can find an , n such that $x^n<1/n$. But I got stuck there playing with the derivative of $a^y-1/y$.

Comment: $x$? $y$? Your question needs some clarifications

Comment: You can compute the limit using "L'Hospitals" and basic tricks from calculus. Since the limit exists, it is the lim sup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} &= e^{\ln\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\right)}\\
&= e^{\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n}}\\
&= e^{-\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}
\end{align*}

Note that by L'Hospital's Rule, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n} = 0.$

So

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n} &= \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{-\frac{\ln(n)}{n}}\\
&= e^{-\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n}}\\
&= e^0\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}

Since the limit exists, the lim sup is equal to it.

Comment: +1 ... Note, that we don't need LHR to show that $\lim \frac{\log(n)}{n}=0$.  We have $\log(x)\le x-1$ for $x>0$ and $\log(x^a)=a\log(x)\le x^a-1$.  For any $a>0$, $\log(x)\le \frac{x^a -1}{a}$ so $\frac{\log(x)}{x}\le \frac{x^{a-1}-x^{-1}}{a}$ for all $a>0$.  Take any $0<a<1$ and let $x\to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

One has

$$\log{\left({1\over n}\right)^{1\over n}}={1\over n}\log{1\over n}$$

Now $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x\log{x}=0$ so the limit of the sequence above exists and is $1$. And so the $\limsup$ is $1$ as well

Answer (score 1):

### non standard solution

Consider the series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \frac1n \cdot z^n$. Since $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} z^n$ converges for all $z \in \mathbb C$ with $|z| \lt 1$ and it holds that $|\frac 1n \cdot z| \le |z|$, the series also converges for these $z$. Furthermore, $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \frac1n \cdot 1$ does not converge, ie. the the convergence radius is $1$.

By the convergence radius formula one gets $1 = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\frac1n|^\frac1n}$.